# Trouble in getting rid of warning in glassfish server

Tags: spring, jpa, glassfish

Hi I tried to run a Spring JPA application in glassfish server the application is up and running but everytime a DB query is getting accessed the below warning is displayed in the logs:

javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer

Error while Resizing pool MediaTrackPool. Exception : WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped.

Though there is no problem with the app running but everytime the warning is displayed. Can some one help me in getting rid of the same.

Comment: There is a [Code Ranch article](http://www.coderanch.com/t/613225/glassfish/GlassFish-Server-connect-SQL-database) about this problem but it is inconclusive.